# Passing an optional object to all views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So, basically what I'd like is to do something like:

```
@if(Notification!=null){
     //perform javascript notification with @Notification.Text
 }
```

And I'd like to be able to do this on any view, so I will always have the option of specifying a notification object in my controller action, that, if defined, can be handled in the view.

My dream scenario is to allow this simply by creating the Notification object somehow, and then just returning the view. Meaning, I wouldn't need to explicitly pass the Notification object to the model. Like so:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(){
    Notification n = new Notification("Text for javascript");
    return View();
}
```

I'm thinking, that there might be a way to do this with some ViewPage-inheritance? But I'm really unsure of how to go about this?

In an ideal world, I would also love to be able to "override" what to do. For example, if I in my 'top'-layout choose to perform a certain kind of jquery-notification if the notification object exists, but maybe in some other nested view would like to handle it differently, I'd like the option to override the top-layouts handling of the object.

I know this last thing might be a little utopian (I'm just starting out with MVC and Razor), but it would be cool :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ViewBag for simple stuff like popup message.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.PopupMessage = "Hello!";
    return View();
}
```

and then in view (or layout page)

```
@if (ViewBag.PopupMessage != null)
{
    <div class="popup">@ViewBag.PopupMessage</div>
}
```

For more complicated stuff you will need to either create static class and save/read from `HttpContext.Current.Items` or override `Controller` and `WebViewPage` and save/read from `ViewBag`/`ViewData`.

**Update:**

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public const string NotificationKey = "_notification";

    protected string Notification
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewData[NotificationKey] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewData[NotificationKey] = value;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class BaseViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    protected string Notification
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewData[BaseController.NotificationKey] as string;
        }
    }
}
```

Views/Web.config

```
<pages pageBaseType="OverrideTest.Framework.BaseViewPage">
```

Usage:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Notification = "Hello from index!";

        return View();
    }
}

<div>Notification: @(Notification ?? "(null)")</div>
```

Or get test project [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1799304/OverrideTest.7z)

**Update 2:**
Check out [this](http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/adding-rails-like-flash-message-in-asp-dot-net-mvc) blog post for another way to do something similar.

Comment: I see the appeal of using viewbag for the simple stuff. The more complicated stuff intrigues me though, could you elaborate a little on the overrides?

Comment: Updated my post :) It is basically just wrapping around ViewData/ViewBag because in controller you don't know whether there will be view or not. Note that it doesn't have to be string, you can easily replace that with complex object for example.

Comment: I have a quick follow-up. I implemented your solution with a custom notification object. In the view, there's no @Notification intellisense, and it tries to get me to specify the class "Notification" - it works fine though, but is there anything I can do to get the view intellisense to cooperate? :)

Comment: Have you tried to turn it off and on again? (seriously, intellisense sometimes ignore web.config changes :) )

Comment: :) I couldn't find the place where you enable/disable it, but a restart worked fine :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

You could write a custom global action filter which will inject this information on all views. For example:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Notification = new Notification("Text for javascript");                 
    }
}
```

and then register this filter in the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method of your `Global.asax`:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new MyActionFilterAttribute());
}
```

And then in your views:

```
@if(ViewBag.Notification != null) 
{
     //perform javascript notification with @ViewBag.Notification.Text
}
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for, as this would mean the notification would always get sent to the viewbag. I'd like to specify when and where and under what conditions to do this in the controller action :)

Comment: @Dynde, I don't understand. In your question you said that you were looking for a way to pass this information on all views and now you talk about conditions in controller actions. If you want to do it in the controller action then simply put this code in your view model and populate it in the controller action.

Comment: actually I said "...any view..." not every view and "...so I will always have the option...". And the reason I'm not using the ViewModel is because I see this need (I used the notification just as an example) as something much more generic than the ViewModel - which is meant to be more or less specific, in context to the View in question.